# Empty char array after using readurl

Tags: matlab

i need to get Adj Close values of Apple security by using

```
str = urlread('http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=2&b=18&c=2017&d=3&e=18&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv');
```

but i always get empty char array as result. This url works when i use it in web browser and all other webs i have tried with urlread worked perfectly. Somehow only getting CSVs from yahoo finance never works for me. I have tried urlwrite too, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you change it to https

```
str = urlread('https://chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=2&b=18&c=2017&d=3&e=18&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv');
```